# calling translate() twice in one select in XSL

Tags: xml, debugging, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to replace the true and false in my columns with yes and no. So far this code does not work, I can't call `translate` twice in one statement. Please help.

```
<td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@isadmin, 'False', 'no'), translate(@isadmin, 'True', 'yes') "/>
</td>
```

Comment: Please do not tag your questions as both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0: they are meant to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you replacing a whole string or part of it? It is not clear what you are doing. If the whole string is either "True" or "False" then this seems a bit crazy to use replace. Just test on the value. Using XSL 1.0 you could just use a simple test on the whole string, or perhaps use contains() if more is in there:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@isadmin = 'True')">
     <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of short and cryptic coding, you might like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@isadmin, 'TruFalse', 'yesno')"/>
```

Personally, I prefer something a bit more verbose and a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily call translate() twice in one statement; just remember that it returns a string, and nest the calls:

```
translate(translate(@isadmin, 'False', 'no'), 'True', 'yes')
```

If the original value is 'False', the inner call translates the 'F' to 'n', the 'a' to 'o', and the 'l', 's', and 'e' to the empty string; the outer call then finds that there are no occurrences of the letters 'T', 'r', 'u', or 'e' and does nothing.  If the original value is 'True', then the inner call translates the 'e' to the empty string leaving the value 'Tru', and the outer call translates 'T' to 'y', 'r' to 'e', and 'u' to 's'.  If you are using XSLT 2.0, it may be less complicated to use replace() instead:

```
replace(replace(@isadmin, 'False', 'no'), 'True', 'yes')
```

These are almost as compact as the solution offered by michael.hor257k, and slightly less tricky; there is also nothing wrong with the more verbose solutions offered by others.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `replace()` function and treat the different cases in different templates. Assuming you are matching `<column>` elements with an `isadmin` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="column[@isadmin='False']">
    <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(@isadmin, 'False', 'no')"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column[@isadmin='True']">
    <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(@isadmin, 'True', 'yes')"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

**UPDATE**: I didn't notice it while I was answering your question, but as @michael.hor257k observes in the comment, you don't really have to use *any function at all* if you make your selection using templates and predicates as shown above. You could simply use:

```
<xsl:template match="column[@isadmin='False']">
    <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
        <xsl:text>no</xsl:text>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column[@isadmin='True']">
    <td align="Left" class="tableNormalRow">
        <xsl:text>yes</xsl:text>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

---

The `translate()` function replaces *individual characters* found in the string passed as first parameter that exist in the second parameter, with the characters in the third parameter *in the same position*. In your case it worked because the string in `@isadmin` *is an exact match* and *longer* than the replacement string. It wouldn't be possible, for example, to revert that. This:

```
translate('no', 'no', 'False')
```

would result in `'Fa'`, not `'False'`, because the `n` would be replaced by the `F`, the `'o'` would be replaced by the `'a'`, and the other characters would be discarded.

Note: The `replace()` function only exists in **XSLT 2.0 or +**.

Comment: If you're matching on `column[@isadmin='False']` then doing replace() is redundant, isn't it?